# Drupal Page Title Block

Tags: twig, block, drupal-8

Today I've try to add image_field in "Page Title" block.

I don't know if it's possible ?

If it isn't possible, it is possible to add field_image in twig template ?

Tnks.

Comment: Anything is possible. Can you show the code you tried?

Comment: I've just tried to use twig like this : {{ node.field_image.title }} (title to test), just in field--node--title.html.twig. I don't know if it's the best way to made this... Thks for the quick response ;)

Comment: I just realized you are using Drupal. I'm not familiar with Drupal. Maybe someone else can suggest something?

Comment: Have you tried just content.field_image?

Comment: Yes I've tried it and this not work...

Comment: The page-title template, doesnt have access to other fields other than title directly. So your best case is to write a preprocess function and add the field you want as part of the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below may help you. First im adding a theme suggestion for page_title, so that i can control the place where i have to over ride the template. I am adding node_type - as suffix to the template.

Then i am adding the preprocess function- make sure you replace the signature with the type you want "news" at the end should be replaced with your content type from the first function.

In the second function i am fetching a field called subtitle, and adding the value to variables so that it is available in the template.

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array &$variables, $hook) {
  if($hook === 'page_title') {
    if($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')){
        $node_type = $node->getType();
        // suggestion must use _ and __ as per convention.
        $suggestions[] = 'page_title__'.$node_type;
    }
  }
}


function mytheme_preprocess_page_title__news(&$variables) {

  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    try {
      if ($node->get('field_subtitle') && !$node->get('field_subtitle')->isEmpty()) {
        $variables['sub_title'] =
          $node->get('field_subtitle')
            ->get(0)
            ->get('value')
            ->getValue();
      }
    }catch(Exception $e){

      \Drupal::logger('mytheme')->error($e);
    }
  }
}
```

Now in the template you will sub_title available in the template file, in my case it was page-title--news.html.twig - copied from page-title.html.twig and added respective variable.

Comment: For got to add the above functions should be in your mytheme.theme file

Comment: Hi, I've tried to use your function with some modification to adapt at my theme. but when I try to see what I have in the variable (for you 'sub_title') with kint(), it say 'NULL'

Comment: Have you tried to kint in the function itself for the variable values ? are you fetching the values properly from the field, image field values are does not have the same structure as the text field. In my case i am fetching text field.

Comment: @C.MARTIN Could you please share your code as well ? with the modifications ?

Comment: Hi,
I've just modified field_subtitle by field_image aind sub_title by fimage.
I use {{ fimage }} to display that I want.
I've olso replaced mytheme by the name of my theme (same as the name of folder theme. (In function and in catch). I can't post the code...

Comment: And today I've just tried this function religv1_preprocess_test(&$variables) {
 $variables['test'] = "Access Ok";
}  And I've used {{ test }} to display "Access Ok", this does not work...

Comment: the function must be of the signature MODNAME_preprocess_page_title

Comment: First you can try with a generic preprocess, like MODNAME_preprocess_page_title - then you can add custom template and custom preprocess.

Comment: Ok so I've tried this and I got result with other function : Get node, get field_image target id, load file and after I can use Uri. But I did not succed to have field with <img> (html tag)